# Simple audio recording function that records for 5 seconds then saves.

Tags: audio, media, recorder

I looked at every post but have not found the solution here. I'm running a timed threaded function, I need to have the function record for a few seconds and save the recording to a file. Any links to point me to such a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps:

- choose one slice size window to capture the sound like (1024, 2048)
- Make a loop from 0 to (frame_rate / slice_size * seconds_duration)
- Open one stream record w/ the same silce window
- put all data in one vector
- At end of loop, open one file like wav, set the headers, set the
  number of channels, set the frame rate and write your vector in this
  file !

All done, do you have one recorded file!

Comment: Yes, I was correct. No links. It wasn't an oversight on my part. Thank you anyway.